# Firebase + Android + Spring to create microservices

Tags: android, spring, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is the idea:

- There is an android application that will consume services that I will create using Spring. However, this services should have some sort of security, so only people logged in on my android app can consume such services.
- On my android app, I will use Firebase to do the authentication, using email and password. So, there will be no need for me to configure any server to make this control. (Like Spring OAuth2)

The question is, once the user is logged on my app and wants to consume some service, for example GET LIST of something, that I will provide on the Server using Spring, how can I check if the user is logged on the app, so I can grant access to that service?

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server/verify-id-tokens

Comment: That's what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Android app will need to pass the user's token on to your app server, where you can then verify that the id token is valid and use the information in it.

See the [Firebase documentation on verifying id tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server/verify-id-tokens) for full information, including this description:

> If your Firebase client app communicates with a custom backend server, you might need to identify the currently signed-in user on that server. To do so securely, after a successful sign-in, send the user's ID token to your server using HTTPS. Then, on the server, verify the integrity and authenticity of the ID token and retrieve the uid from it. You can use the uid transmitted in this way to securely identify the currently signed-in user on your server.

Also note this first note in blue:

> Note: Many use cases for verifying ID tokens on the server can be accomplished by using Security Rules for the [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) and [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/). See if those solve your problem before verifying ID tokens yourself.

While it might not apply for your use-case, always keep it in mind since the most maintainable code is the code that you didn't have to write. :-)